# Visibility Collapsed leaving a slight space in the UI

Tags: wpf, xaml

Given the following xaml structure

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>Block 1</TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>Block 2</TextBlock>
         </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">Block 3</TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>Block 4</TextBlock>
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>Block 5</TextBlock>
           <TextBlock>Block 6</TextBlock>
         </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

I expect this output:

```
Block 1 Block 2 
Block 4 
Block 5 Block 6
```

But I get this

```
Block 1 Block 2 
 Block 4   
Block 5 Block 6
```

Where is the space before `Block 4` coming from, and how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), you can see that this is from a `ContainerVisual` that wraps your child `TextBlock`s. Since `TextBlock` is trying to display a collection of `Inline` derived objects (this is generally abstracted away), it must wrap your `TextBlock` in a `ContainerVisual`.

Since these are the actual objects getting arranged by the parent `TextBlock`, and they don't even have the `Visibility` property, you are going to need to refactor your code a bit. I imagine that you're trying to bind to a number of separate properties, and want to display them in one TextBlock. You could fix this a couple of ways:

- Make a `IMultiValueConverter` and pass a bunch of properties controlling what to show
- Construct the complex string in your `ViewModel`
- Replace the outer `TextBlock` with a `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`

I'd recommend the last, as it is the easiest.

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock>Block 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Block 2</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">Block 3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Block 4</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock>Block 5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Block 6</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```